# Is "Please be submitted" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, imperative-sentences

Is it grammatically correct to write

> Please be submitted the monthly financial report.

Instead of writing the following?

> I would like to make a monthly financial report.

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. The first sentence is unidiomatic, but I would understand it to mean a request for somebody else to make a submission (or, grammatically, asking the report to submit itself somehow).

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "*make* a report".  Report in to someone *viva voce*, summarizing the month's salient events or data?

Comment: "Please be submitted the monthly financial report." is definitely wrong. I would assume it was meant to mean "Please make sure the report id submitted" rather than "I would like to submit a report"."

Answer (score 1):

The traditional wording for a covering letter with a document is *Please find enclosed...*, or for an electronic submission *please find attached...*, but that is rather old-fashioned and formal. You can just say *I attach...* or *Attached is...*.

It's the report that is 'being submitted', not the recipients!

Answer (score 1):

"Please be [adjective phrase]" is a polite *command*. It instructs the person or persons addressed to put themselves in the state of [adjective phrase].

> Please be seated.
>
> Please be quiet.
>
> Please be prompt.
>
> Please be on time.

That form of command does not accept either a direct object or a "passive" subject in the position highlighted:

> Please be on time  **the bus**. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> Please be submitted **the report**. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

But it can have a sentient subject there, in vocative mode, addressing the person(s) so instructed:

> Please be quiet, kids.
>
> Please be seated, people.
>
> Please be on time, Bob.

P.S. It is also possible to *personify* an object as if it were capable of hearing and heeding your words, and this kind of "command" is more  an *entreaty* than an order or instruction:

> Please be on time, bus!
>
> Please be submitted, report!

Note there the absence of a determiner.

Answer (score 0):

"Please submit the monthly financial report" is a request for someone to submit or attach a report.

"I would like to submit a monthly financial report" notifies the recipient of your intent to do something, i.e., submit or attach a report.